# Filename giving 3d prefix auto in php

Tags: php, pdf, filenames, attachment

// Attach the PDF

```
$message .= "--$boundary\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Report.pdf\r\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" .
            base64_encode($output) . "\r\n";
```

here attaching filename the report.pdf goes to 3dReport.pdf how to get  only Report.pdf

How to get  report.pdf as a filename  instead  of 3dreport.pdf

Comment: `3d` is the hexadecimal equivalent of `=`. Try enclosing the filename within double quotes. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Just use a mailing library and it will take care of all the details for you.

Comment: As Olivier says, building this yourself is fiddly, error-prone and unnecessary: Use a free mailing library such as PHPMailer where someone has already solved this for you, and you can just call an "addAttachment()" function easily to include your attachment. Unless you have an academic interest in how the mechanics of email content work, there is really no point trying to re-invent the wheel here.